# Customizing Foundation Grid Rows

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation CSS for my website.

I need to customize some of the styles of the Row class. I need to control its Height as in some place the gap between two rows is too much which i want to reduce. Also is it possible that i can add a Pointer Cursor and some background color on the rows where ever i need it.

This is the way i have initialized, and till now not added any custom style.

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Please advice me as how can i customize the Zurb foundation for my needs.

Comment: I use `foundation` often. Let me give you a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can customize your properties of your `gutter` with this handy tool:**

http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation

Just save the file and include it as your base, and you're ready to roll with the least effort possible.

[image]

Alternatively, you can edit the `CSS` yourself, but there are a **lot** of properties you would have to alter to make it work efficiently.

The other alternative if you just want to alter **ONE** `element` is to load a `custom CSS file` **after** you load `foundation`, as that will override just a specific `class` that you can apply to any `elements` you want.

## Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

**In `style.css`:**

```
.yourClass {
    padding: 0;
    background: #CCC;
}
.yourClass:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="yourClass">Content</div>
```

I have all kinds of custom styling going on here at a site I'm currently building:

- http://www.sinsysonline.com/secondhomehostel

Comment: **I believe I tackled everything?** Let me know if there are questions.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. The Customize Link option is a good one. But that suggests that if i customize the Row Height of the row class, it will get implemented in all places. In most places the Grid layout works. But in 1 place i need a more compact Grid Layout. I want to override for that Grid only. Writing my own css class for that is an option, but then it will mean mixed css of mine and Foundation which i want to avoid till i can.

Comment: As mentioned in the `example`, I use this all the time. Just load your `custom stylesheet` **after** your `foundation.css`. It works perfect. Just add a `class` to your `element` in question.

Comment: Nicholas i am a bit confused as i am using this for the 1st time.  Lets say i have a <div class='row'>. now i want the row height to half with no top or bottom margin. so what changes do i need to make in the Custom Download page. Also After downloading the Custom CSS, will i need to manually change the classes name or it will have somthing like 
<div class='rowcustom'>

Comment: **You can add multiple classes easily**. Use `<div class='row rowcustom'>`

Comment: sorry for the incomplete comment earlier. Have edited it

Comment: Edited answer, and I believe I've solved the problem. Feel free to accept this as an appreciable answer by using the green checkbox next to the voting arrows.